# Meta tags from URL (discord)

Tags: javascript, html, discord

I'm making a website that lets you create custom discord embeds and show them by sending a premade link.
The way the links work is like this `https://example.site/?title=thisIsTitle&desc=thisIsDesc` and it will extract the `title=` and `desc=` to js strings.

How would I then use those strings in meta tags so they show up in the discord embed?

Comment: "Tell me if I should move this to a different subreddit." You do know you're not in Reddit, right?

Comment: I copied this from a reddit post I made and forgot to remove that

Comment: Oh, makes sense.